How do I send 401 response with custom login_required decorator after Django session expires?
I have a custom login_required decorator that looks like this:
def login_required(function):
    """
    Ensure that user is logged in
    """

    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_anonymous:
            message = {
                "status": "error",
                "message": "user login error",
                "data": "user is not logged in",
            }
            return HttpResponse(
                content=json.dumps(message).encode("utf-8"),
                status=401,
                headers=None,
                content_type="application/json",
            )
        return function(request, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrap

When my request comes in and the Django session has expired, I see my custom message in the response. However, the status code of the response is 302, redirected with the /accounts/login/?next= in the URL.
I have configured SESSION_TIMEOUT_REDIRECT, LOGOUT_REDIRECT, LOGIN_URL in settings. I have tried configuring different Django settings but no success so far.
This is the middleware i am using:
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "csp.middleware.CSPMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django_session_timeout.middleware.SessionTimeoutMiddleware",
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    "core.middleware.admin_pages_middleware.AdminPagesMiddleware",
]

Tech stack

Python 3.12
Django 5.0

I want my response to be 401 and not 302.
Could you please let me know what am I missing?

Your 302 response comes from the django_session_timeout.middleware.SessionTimeoutMiddleware middleware which I guess comes from this package. Since middleware run before the view your view never gets the chance to run.
Given you don't seem to want to redirect the user when their session expires you might as well do away with it and just set the SESSION_COOKIE_AGE setting to an appropriate value to expire the users session or if you're using their package for its feature of expiring the session N seconds after "last activity" you'll need to fork their package and change their middleware (Present in this file) to return your custom response instead of redirecting the user.

Thanks Abdul for the explanation! If the view does not get a chance to run, how would you explain the custom error message from my decorator showing up in the response?

Also, I want to redirect users but I am handling it in my React frontend to redirect users to login page on 401 response.
However, is there a way to configure redirection in django settings? Configuring SESSION_TIMEOUT_REDIRECT did not work for me.

@Vroom "how would you explain the custom error message from my decorator showing up in the response" you don't show enough code for me to answer that, it's likely due to whatever code you have on the frontend. Also if you're doing this for an API that your frontend will be calling then as I mentioned you very much should not be using that middleware.
